# How can I make an XML block from one file look like another file?

Tags: xml, powershell

Using Powershell, I want to automate the mass modification of xml templates.
There are 2 files that have the same structure but different controls and i need to bring them to a common view.
file1.xml is the reference. i need to bring the contents of the Tester group to file2.xml to the reference type.

How do I do this correctly? ReplaceChild or clear the group first and then ImportNode?
I am very grateful in advance for your help

```
#file1.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FORM>
<Group>
  <Column PercentWidth="20">
    <Group Label="Tester">
      <Column PercentWidth="100">
            <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints" Type="FieldControl" Label="Label1" LabelPosition="Left" />
            <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority" Type="FieldControl" Label="Label2" LabelPosition="Left" />
            <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity" Type="FieldControl" Label="Label3" LabelPosition="Left" />
      </Column>
    </Group>
  </Column>
</Group>
</FORM>


#file2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FORM>
<Group>
  <Column PercentWidth="20">
    <Group Label="Tester">
      <Column PercentWidth="100">
      <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity" Type="FieldControl" Label="Label1" LabelPosition="Left" />
      <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority" Type="FieldControl" Label="Label2" LabelPosition="Left" />
      <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints" Type="FieldControl" Label="Label4" LabelPosition="Left" />
      </Column>
    </Group>
  </Column>
</Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace one node from one document with a different one from another document, you can use the `ReplaceChild()` method.

```
# Read files into XML objects
$file1 = [xml](Get-Content file1.xml)
$file2 = [xml](Get-Content file2.xml)

# Use XPATH to find nodes to copy and replace
$nodeToReplace = $file1.FORM.Group.Column.SelectSingleNode('./Group[@Label="Tester"]')
$nodeToCopy = $file2.FORM.Group.Column.SelectSingleNode('./Group[@Label="Tester"]')

# Import the node so that the copied node will inherit the target document context
$newnode = $file1.ImportNode($NodeToCopy,$true)

# Replace the node
$file1.FORM.Group.Column.ReplaceChild($newnode,$nodeToReplace)
$file1.Save('C:\PathToXML\file1.xml')
```

Obviously, the XPATHs can be tweaked to make this more dynamic just in case this question is more hypothetical.